# AutoCompleteBox in Silverlight 4 bound to dictionary - show only values issue

Tags: dictionary, silverlight-4.0, autocompletebox

I have used AutoCompleteBox usercontrol. I have a dictionary of type `Dictionary<int,string>` which contains ids and names. I want to show only names in the AutoCompleteBox. I can do it with

```
autoCompleteBox1.ItemsSource = dict.Values;
```

My problem is whenever any name is selected I want to retrieve the id associated with it. But I don't want to display the ids to the user as those are for internal purpose. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used following :

```
<AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDict}" ValueMemberPath="Value">
   <AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text={Binding Value}/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</AutoCompleteBox>
```